# Customized Button Template with Binding StringFormat Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

When I am working on a button template I just encountered a binding StringFormat issue. Here it is.

-- I setup a button with a given ToolTip as a string. I like to use it to specify the image name within binding. Then I apply it to a button style called ImageButton.

```
<Button ToolTip="Minimize" Height="34" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}"  Margin="220,36,125,371" />;
```

-- This is the code in style. I like to use the image name from the binding and come up with a full image path. It is supposed to be working like this, `<Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Source="Images/Minimize-Normal.png" />`. Yes, I do have such a image in place and it works great if I just put the xml code without binding.

```
<Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Source="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat={}Images/{0}-Normal.png}" />
```

But the binding did not work as I expected. The image cannot be shown correctly. If I put the Image full name in ToolTip then it worked correct. It looks like the StringFormat had been ignored.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for dbaseman's response. I know I can achieve it by using Converter. But as I think StringFormat is easier to apply, that's why I tried this.

I also found a reply here, it says - StringFormat is used when binding to a string property, while the Text property in your control is of type object, hence StringFormat is ignored.

---

It should be by design. Below code works. Because the Text property is string type.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat={}Images/{0}-Normal.png}" ToolTip="Minimize" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's interesting -- I'm not sure if it's a bug, or by design.  You can work around this problem, though, by using a `Converter` instead of `StringFormat`.

```
public class ImageNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("Images/{0}-Normal.png", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then of course:

```
<local:ImageNameConverter x:Key="ImageNameConverter" />
```

And:

```
<Image x:Name="ButtonImage" 
    Source="{Binding ToolTip, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                Converter="{StaticResource ImageNameConverter}}" />
```

---

**Edit** I think it's by design.  From the [docs for BindingBase.StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx):

> Gets or sets a string that specifies how to format the binding if it displays the bound value as a string.

So (apparently) the string-format conversion won't happen unless the binding source is to actually be rendered as a text string.